# Encoded characters shown in HTML file

Tags: java, html, encoding, utf-8

My Html file showed this of errors while I was converting it into pdf

> â€oe Cover Pageâ€

in the generated pdf.

I understood it was an encoding error and tried to specify

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

in the html file. No change.

But the problem now is, even in my html file these encoded characters are getting displayed:

```
<strong>â€œ <span style="text-decoration: underline;">
           Technology</span>â€�
```

What is the reason for this and do I have to manually remove these characters in the file?

**Edit**: I'm converting the HTML to pdf using this:

```
        String html = templateEngine.process("template", context);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PDFGenerator.createPdf(html, bos);
        byte[] outArray = bos.toByteArray();
        String fileName = "abc" + ".pdf";
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                PDFGenerator.createPdf(html, bos);
                byte[] outArray = bos.toByteArray();
                response.reset();
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.setContentLength(outArray.length);
                response.setHeader("Expires:", "0");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                        "attachment; filename="" + fileName + "\"");
                FileCopyUtils.copy(outArray, response.getOutputStream());
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
```

where response is HttpServletResponse

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8">` only _declares_ that this HTML should be decoded by browser/receiver with `utf-8`, to make this _declaration_ stands, you need to save the html source in `utf-8` as you claimed.   check [applyingencoding](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-encodings#applyingencoding)

Comment: Just had a little try, `â€œ` will show if you try using `windows-1252` encoding to decode `“` ([U+201C](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm))  that was originally encoding with `utf-8`.

So try to change your file editor's encoding to utf-8 instead of windows-1252 will show your the correct html.

As for PDF, look for whether `PDFGenerator` allows to explicitly set an encoding or not.